# Updating TYPO3 4.7 to version 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5, typo3-4.7

I've updated a TYPO3 website from 4.7 to version 6.2.12. As I do so I replaced deprecated classes with the proper namespaces.

- `t3lib_div` to `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility` or
- `t3lib_extmgm` to `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility`

Now the old extensions are installed. But now I'm facing an error with security extension like this

> Oops, an error occurred!
>
> Invalid form/module token detected. Access Denied!
>
> More information regarding this error might be available online.(https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1392409507)

And in other extension I have this error i think it is the same problem

> Validating the security token of this form has failed. Please reload the form and submit it again.

I absolutely have no clue what I need to do, any suggestions?

Comment: Go to "Install tool > upgrade wizard" and follow all upgrade steps. second things you donot need to replace deprecated classes manually, just install "compatibility6" extension.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It doesn't work, i do upgrade from 4.7 to 6.2 and the extension was developed on 4.7 :/

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the [CSRF Form Protection](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/6.2/ApiOverview/FormProtection/). 
Please check the [commit that introduced this](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/repository/revisions/6e9e5455ba0c656e50ce94bc08d988bba9ec642e).

Make sure to use `BackendUtility::getModuleUrl()` for each place you generate  a link.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me alot. :)